# Generate Test data in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

How I can generate quickly data for this Oracle table?

```
Table EVENTS

EVENTID NUMBER(38,0)
AGENTID NUMBER(38,0)
EVENTDATE   DATE
CPU NUMBER(38,0)
RAM NUMBER
HDD NUMBER
NETWORKUP   NUMBER
NETWORKDOWN NUMBER
```

For example can I do 1000 insets with Oracle function?

Comment: Yes, Oracle supports inserting 1000 rows into a table.  Your question really is not clear.

Comment: Can you show me quick function of generating and inserting 1000 rows into the table?

Comment: `INSERT INTO events SELECT 1,2,SYSDATE,4,5,6,7 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=1000`

Answer (score 0):

can use a procedure and call it whenever required.

```
create or replace procedure addata is
begin
for i in 1..1000 loop

insert into events (EVENTID,
AGENTID ,
EVENTDATE, 
CPU, 
RAM ,
HDD ,
NETWORKUP, 
NETWORKDOWN) values 

(i,
i+1,
sysdate,
i+3,
i+4,
i+5,
i+6,
i+7) ;

end loop;
commit;
end;


SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> exec addata;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select count(*) from events;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1000
```